# Rotate through views result weekly

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type called "Tips of the Week" and in a Views block. I would like to display one tip at a time, but have it display the next tip in a week's time based on the content's post date. If a tip is added, it is entered into the rotation of the tips.

A tip might not be added every week, so I do not think it can be solely based on the post date of the tips. Instead, is there a way to cycle through the offset.

I have tried different sort criteria, and the closest one I could find was random, but that changes every time the page loads.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: So if a new tip isn't added what gets displayed next week?

Comment: If it's at the latest tip and a new one isn't added, I would like it to begin at the oldest tip.

Comment: This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

Comment: @NikhilM This question is from so long ago that I don't even work with Drupal anymore. I probably will not update the question because I honestly don't know where Views is at anymore. If anybody would like to edit/update the question, feel free.

Answer (score 0):

Add a date field to your tip of the week content type.  That date field will indicate when the tip becomes visible on the site.  Order your view by date (descending), and filter out all entries where the date field is greater than the current date.

If you want to write some code, you can add a hook that runs when you submit the form, and, if you leave the date field blank, have it select the maximum value of the date field out of the database, add a week to that, and fill the date in automatically.

Comment: I've updated my question, as I don't think I explained it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should try arguments in Views. Add Date (Node Posted) as an argument.

**Action to take if argument is not present:**

Select *Provide default argument*
and then *Current Date*

Select *Granularity:* as week

Check *Node: Post date* from Date Fields

They way for every week tip of current week will be filter to show.

Comment: I've updated my question, as I don't think I explained it correctly.